# Prove by induction - about vector spaces, polynomials

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, induction

I know how to prove by induction in general but in this task I don't even understand how to do and apply it, it's last task from an old exam:

> $\mathbb{R}_{n}[x]= \left\{\sum_{k=0}^{n}p_{k}x^{k}: p_{k} \in
> \mathbb{R}\right\}$ is the vector space of all real polynomial $p$ of
>   the degree $n_{p} \leq n$. And for every $j \in
> \left\{0,1,...,n\right\}$ there is a polynomial $P_{j} \in
> \mathbb{R}_{n}[x]$ given with degree $np_{j}=j$, that means $P_{j}$
>   has the shape $$P_{j}= \sum_{k=0}^{j}p_{jk}x^{k} \text{ with } p_{jk}
> \in \mathbb{R} \text{ for } k \in \left\{0,1,...,j\right\} \text{ and
> } p_{jj} \neq 0$$
>
> Prove by induction that $\left\{P_{0},..., P_{n}\right\}$ is a basis
>   of $\mathbb{R_{n}[x]}$, if $\mathbb{R}_{0}[x]$  is identified with
>   $\mathbb{R}$.

If this was in my exam, I wouldn't know at all what to do and where to start. There are so so many different variables and attributes given... I would be very happy already if I knew how to do the start (I mean where you just show it for a specific $n$, the begin). Usually, induction proofs were easy when I had them in analysis classes but this is something very different and much more complicated I don't know how to start here? >.<

Comment: One place to start would be to try a small case.  When $n=3$ what are $P_0$, $P_1$, $P_2$, and $P_3$?  That can help you fill in what all the symbols represent.

Comment: By the way, what is a polynom?

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint I will do that on paper now and see. Oh I meant polynomial!

Comment: Aha.  Beware of premature abbreviation—it detracts from readability.

Comment: Was rather a bad translation.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need the set of $\{p_0,p_2,\cdots, p_n\}$ to span the space and to be linearly independent.

And since the space of $\mathbb R_n[x]$ has dimension $n+1$ and there are $n+1$ vectors in our proposed basis, you really only need to prove that the set is linearly independent.

Base case:
$n=0$

$p_0 = c$ spans the set of real numbers

Suppose:
$\{p_0,p_2,\cdots, p_n\}$ is a basis for $R_n[x]$

We must show that:

$\{p_0,p_2,\cdots, p_n, p_{n+1}\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb R_{n+1}[x]$

$p_{n+1}$ has an $x^{n+1}$ term that $\{p_0,p_2,\cdots, p_n\}$ do not.

$p_{n+1}$ cannot be formed by a linear combination of $\{p_0,p_2,\cdots, p_n\}$

$\{p_0,p_2,\cdots, p_n, p_{n+1}\}$ are a linearly indpendent set of vectors that spans $\mathbb R_{n+1}[x]$ and therefor form a basis for $\mathbb R_{n+1}[x]$

QED

Comment: Thank you too, how much time did you need to find that out? I'm at the moment trying to understand the way you solved it :D

Comment: It took a couple of minutes to understand what $P_j$ was(and how it would be different from $P_{j-1}$.  Then it was pretty quick to think about what we needed to show to form a basis.